# IntelliJ Debug Console does not display all lines

Tags: intellij-idea, console, output

I am new to intelliJ. In the debug console exception output gets cut at some point and displays lines similar to "... 54 more" etc. An example image is below:

[image]

How can I see full output instead "... 54 more"?